# Can't pass label to ARM macro?

Tags: assembly, macros, arm

Here's my macro:

```
        ; Good old DJNZ meets ARM!

        MACRO
        DJNZ  $register, $target
            SUBS    $register, $register, #1
            BNE     $target
        MEND
```

And my usage:

```
DELAY       PROC
                PUSH    {R2, LR}                   ; Push the changed registers & link register

WAIT_OUTER      LDR     R2, =40000                 ; Length of inner loop

WAIT_INNER      DJNZ    R2, WAIT_INNER
                DJNZ    R0, WAIT_OUTER

                POP     {R2, PC}                   ; Pop & return
            ENDP
```

I'm getting this error:

```
== Compiling main.asm to main.o ==
"main.asm", line 167 (column 9): Error: A1516E: Bad symbol 'WAIT_INNER', not defined or external
    at line 167 in macro DJNZ in 'macros.s'

  167 000000d0    BNE  WAIT_INNER
                       ^
1 Error, 0 Warnings
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Ideas what's wrong? According to the manual, passing labels into macros should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like armasm has some slightly unintuitive [syntax](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361290018802.htm) when it comes to labels and macros, although [the examples](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1359731155623.htm) do make it a bit clearer.

Long story short, you're not defining the label `WAIT_INNER` at the start of the line there, you're actually passing it as another argument to the macro. However, since the macro doesn't use that argument, it doesn't get expanded anywhere, thus there is no label in the output of the macro expansion pass and you get the error.

The simple fix is to just make the label definition a separate statement from the macro invocation:

```
WAIT_INNER
            DJNZ    R2, WAIT_INNER
            ...
```

The more fiddly option is to explicitly say that any label argument to the macro should appear at the first instruction:

```
       MACRO
$label DJNZ  $register, $target
$label     SUBS    $register, $register, #1
           BNE     $target
       MEND
```